# USERxx variables not usable in action_url and notes_url

Tags: nagios

I am using Nagios Core 3.5.0 and I have the following service definition:

```
service {
    ...
    action_url  http://$USER10$/static/html/node.html?node=$USER3$&host=$HOSTADDRESS$
}
```

The USERxx variables have been set correctly in `resource.cfg`.

However, the URL that gets generated does not get the value at all for the USER variables but gets the value for `HOSTADDRESS`.

Is there something that I need to do to all USER variables to be available for the `action_url` and `notes_url`?

Answer (score 0):

The USER variables should definitely be available, as per here: [Nagios 3.x manual](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/macrolist.html)

In fact, we're running Nagios 3.5.1 and have successfully done this to link to pnp4nagios graphs:

```
define host {
   name       host-pnp
   action_url $USER10$?host=$HOSTNAME$
   register   0
}
```

Have you defined the resource.cfg in your nagios.cfg correctly using something like this?

```
resource_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/resource.cfg
```

My guess is that you've not defined the resource file correctly, so the macros are not being defined.